# Where are the Windows system menu icons stored?

Tags: c#, dll, icons

Where are the Windows system menu icons stored?

I'm talking about the icons on the system context menu.

[image: System menu]

I want to put them in my application.

Comment: How is it unclear? I have clearly provided a picture, explained my goal, and even told you that I have literally researched but found nothing.

Comment: I encourage you to ask on [meta]. If you want to learn how to improve your question you can ask the community politely on Meta and I am sure more users will be able to provide thorough guidance. Asking what to do to make the question better is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get images using the [LoadBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadbitmapa) function.
Example (c#):

```cs
namespace GetBitmap
{
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    internal static class Program
    {
        private const long OBM_RESTORED = 32744;

        private static void Main()
        {
            var hBitmap = LoadBitmap(IntPtr.Zero, OBM_RESTORED);
            var image = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);

            image.Save(@"d:\restored.png", ImageFormat.Png);

            DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadBitmap(IntPtr hInstance, long resourceId);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool DeleteObject([In] IntPtr hObject);
    }
}
```